# How to process uploaded files in correct order?

Tags: google-app-engine

Let's say I have the following form with 2 files:

```html
<!-- the field below contains actual upload file -->
<input type=hidden name="http://localhost:XXXX/some_unique_name_generated_by_Picasa_and_not_controlled_by_me"> 
<!-- the name of field below is equal to the uploaded above filename -->
<input type=hidden name="DSC04310.jpg" value="description of first file">

<input type=hidden name="http://localhost:XXXX/some_unique_name_generated_by_Picasa_and_not_controlled_by_me"> 
<input type=hidden name="DSC04306.jpg" value="description of second file">
```

Somehow when they are uploaded, I get them on the server in different sequence - *DSC04306.jpg* first and then *DSC04310.jpg*. I use:

```py
arguments = self.request.arguments()
files_arguments = []               
for argument in arguments:
    if 'localhost' in argument: # choose files only, not other fields
        files_arguments.append(argument)
```

But I need to process them in the same sequence as they were in the form.
I think about the following solution:

```html
<input type=hidden name="http://localhost:XXXX/some_unique_name"> 
<input type=hidden name="DSC04310.jpg" value="description of first file">
<input type=hidden name="seq_DSC04310.jpg" value="1">

<input type=hidden name="http://localhost:XXXX/some_unique_name"> 
<input type=hidden name="DSC04306.jpg" value="description of second file">
<input type=hidden name="seq_DSC04306.jpg" value="2">
```

Is it good approach? If so, then how can I sort values in `files_arguments` based on values in `seq_FILENAME` fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `request.arguments()`, unless you want all keys from request including keys from the query string (and not only POST). Also, **it is not ordered**.

Instead, iterate over `request.POST` values, because it is ordered. You can use `request.POST.iteritems()` or `request.POST.itervalues()`:

```
for key, value in self.request.POST.iteritems():
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks, moraes, for answering all my GAE-related questions ;). If I use `iteritems`, will I get that in the same order as uploaded?

Comment: It is not something from HTTP spec, but in practical terms, yes.

Comment: I don't think order is guaranteed to be preserved by browsers in the first place, is it? I'm puzzled how it could possibly matter what order the fields are processed in, though.

Comment: @Nick Johnson It is not an HTTP requirement so it is not a server guarantee, but in practical terms it is ordered (and webob's MultiDict keeps the order it gets from headers/body).